# Swift: Add a Textfield when Button is Pushed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

Can anyone tell me how I can make a button, when clicked, add a Textfield and have a limit up to four textfields?

```
class AddNewGameViewController: UIViewController {

var textFields: [UITextField] = []
    let maxTextFields = 4

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func addPlayer(sender: AnyObject) {
        if textFields.count < maxTextFields {
            let textField = UITextField()
            textFields.append(textField)
        }
    }
```

Here is the code I have so far.

Comment: I think this is a "what part of the process do you need help with" question.

Comment: This search might be a place to start: https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+create+uiview+programmatically

Comment: so I have the action code for when the button is pushed.  @IBAction func addPlayers(sender: AnyObject) {    } I just need to know what the code is for adding textfields when the button is pushed

Comment: You have a specific feature you want and  you want us to write it for you. How about you try to figure this out for yourself and come back with questions if you are unable to figure it out? (Hint: It might be easier to have the text fields in place from the beginning, but hidden. Then your button could just un-hide one at a time.)

Comment: @DuncanC  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate approach would be to create the four fields in your storyboard (or .xib) and mark them hidden.  Then, your button code would only need to un-hide them in sequence.

The advantages to that would be easier control of the layout and less work to do on each button action.

Comment: So how would I create a sequence. Here is the code I have so far. @IBAction func addPlayer(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.enabled = false
        
        Player1.hidden = false
        Player2.hidden = false
        Player3.hidden = false
        Player4.hidden = false }

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
var textFields: [UITextField] = []
let textFieldSize = CGSize(width: 97, height: 30)
let maxTextFields = 4

func tappedButton(button: UIButton) {
    if textFields.count < maxTextFields {
        let y = CGFloat(textFields.count) * textFieldSize.height
        let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y), size: textFieldSize))
        view.addSubview(textField)
        textFields.append(textField)
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what I've been looking for, but its not displaying any textfields when the button is pushed.

Comment: i did not specify a `frame` for the textfield and did not add it as a subview. of course that is what you have to do...

Comment: take a look at my edited answer...

Comment: And if you're using AutoLayout you need to set up the constraints on the text field, which gets pretty complex.